# Retrieving Base64 image from MySQL database via python

Tags: python, mysql, base64, mariadb

I will keep this as short as possible. I have a code that sends data to the database at different times in the day. One type of data that is sent is an image from a thermal camera. This part works fine, and encodes the image as a base64 and sends it to the DB in a "LONGBLOB" datatype.

Now, I am making a script to read in the image from the database, but my code is reading the encoded-image string as an integer.

```
 #Audit to the database

with open("C:/Users/danie/Desktop/image7.png", "rb") as image:
        image_read = image.read() 
        Image =base64.b64encode(image_read) 

        sql = "INSERT INTO flirimage (Image) VALUES (%s)"
        arg=('Image')
        cursor.execute(sql % arg)
        db.commit()
```

Now reading in the data and storing it: (THIS CODE WORKS IF YOU SIMPLY READ IN A FILE!!!)

```
import MySQLdb as mariadb
import base64

db = mariadb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="root", passwd="SECRET", 
db="SECRET")
cursor = db.cursor()

ImageEncoded=cursor.execute("select * from flirimage")
db.commit()

image_64_decode=base64.b64decode(ImageEncoded)

filename='C:/Users/danie/Desktop/image_audit.png'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(image_64_decode)

 db.close()
```

When running the code:

```
TypeError: argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'int'

ImageEncoded
Out[38]: 1
```

To me it seems, there is some problem with the way the Base64 string is being saved in the DB. But I could be wrong.

EDIT:

I wanted to show that the data into the database is encoded directly. After running the first code. I didn't include the whole base64 string to this post since it is very long....

```
Image
Out[42]: b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKAAAAB4CAAAAABQyaazAAAgAElEQVR4ARzB68.............................
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When inserting data be sure to use [placeholder values](http://bobby-tables.com/python) and not string interpolation.

Comment: Does the table `flirimage` have exactly one row with one image??  Why bother putting the image into the db; why not simply keep it in a file?

Comment: @RickJames it does at the moment have one row, but I will be adding a timestamp, field location, and field id number. I am simply trying to figure this part out before I add any additional complexity. The image is stored as a file, but needs to be accessed remotely by others who wish to use it for analysis purposes.

Comment: If the "image is stored as a file", why is the database involved at all?  PHP can read the file, then send it to "others".

Comment: @RickJames Via what means? I am sorry if I seem uninformed about this all, it's really because I am. How could the file be sent? Would it be via a server?

Comment: @SwankyTigers - I see most of the code in your Question -- Open, b64encode, echo.  Or they can fetch the image into their own web page using `<img src=http://path-to-your-file>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, I think it will guide me in the right direction. Appreciate it.